# Webpacker fails compilation after I add sass loader npm package

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I really have no idea why I am getting the following:

```
   ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/javascript/packs/application.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
```

when I include sass-loader to package.json with

```
yarn add sass-loader
```

If i remove it with yarn remove sass-loader, webpacker compiles everything with no error

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install an earlier version. In my case i installed version 10.1.1

```
sass-loader@10.1.1
```

and I was able to advance to the next problem... ;-)